# Google Cloud Function in Javascript completes before the function is completed

Tags: javascript, rest, api, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

To explain my use case, I have a GCP compute engine running an in-house built application with support of a RESTful API. What I want to do is to read the RESTful API to check if there are any updates to records in the application.

If there are new records, I want to add it to a BigQUery table that is used to build a report in Data Studio.

I have an issue in that the function completes before the insert in BigQuery is completed. I have added async, await I don't seem to get the right formula for this work for me, so I'm turning to the community for input. I appreciate any advice I can get on this. Here is my code
`
     'use strict';

```
 // Request Data From A URL
 var axios = require('axios');
 var https = require('https');

  // Var Firebase Functions
 var functions = require('firebase-functions');
 const admin = require('firebase-admin');

 // Initalise App
 admin.initializeApp;

// Setting Timeout in Seconds - default is 1 second
// The maximum value for timeoutSeconds is 540, or 9 minutes. Valid values for memory are:
// 128MB, 256MB, 512MB, 1GB, 2GB

const runtimeOpts = {
  timeoutSeconds: 300,
  memory: '512MB'
}

exports.getEmilyNoonreporttoBigQuery = functions
  .runWith(runtimeOpts)
  .region('europe-west1')
  .https.onRequest(async(req, res) => {
   try {
   // Imports the Google Cloud client library
   const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

  // Create a client
  const bigquery = new BigQuery();

  //Make use of a dataset
  const dataset = bigquery.dataset('noonreport');

//Make use of a table
const table = dataset.table('noonreport');

// The API Key
  let apikey = 'API-KEY';

  // Table to get data from
  var apitable = 'noon_report';

  // From were the data comes
  var shipid = '1';

  // Get the current date 
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

  var url = 'https://emily.apps.gl3/api/' + shipid + '/' + apitable + '?apikey=' + apikey + '&syncdate=' + today;
  console.log('today', today);
  console.log('url', url);

  // At request level
  const agent = new https.Agent({  
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  });

//  axios.get(url)
axios.get(url, { httpsAgent: agent })
    .then(resp => {
      try {
      console.log("Response " + resp);
      for(let artno in resp.data.noon_report) {
        // Create the BigQuery Row
          var row = {
            ship: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.ship,
            local_time: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.local_time || resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.report_date,
            status: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.status,
            location: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.location,
            course: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.course,
            next_port: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.next_port,
            ETD: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.ETD,
            ETA: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.ETA,
            distance_made: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.distance_made,
            stoppage: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.stoppage,
            avg_speed: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.avg_speed,  
            mgo_rob: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.mgo_rob,
            mgo_consumed: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.mgo_consumed,
            mgo_received: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.mgo_received,
            fw_rob: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.fw_rob,
            fw_consumed: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.fw_consumed,
            fw_produced: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.fw_produced,
            fw_received: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.fw_received,
            underway_hours: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.underway_hours,
            me_rh: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.me_rh,
            heli_flight_hours: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.heli_flight_hours,
            heli_fuel_consumed: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.heli_fuel_consumed,
            heli_fuel_rob: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.heli_fuel_rob,
            name_of_pilot: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.name_of_pilot,
            nature_of_flight: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.nature_of_flight,
            wind_direction: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.wind_direction,
            wind_force: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.wind_force,
            sea_state: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.sea_state,
            weather: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.weather,
            visibility: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.visibility,
            barometer: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.barometer,
            air_temp: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.air_temp,
            remarks: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.remarks,
            cur_timestamp: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.cur_timestamp,
            cancelled: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.cancelled,
            arrivaldep: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.arrivaldep,
            shorepw: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.shorepw,  
            lo_rob: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.lo_rob,
            lo_consumed: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.lo_consumed,
            petrol_rob: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.petrol_rob,
            petrol_consumed: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.petrol_consumed,
            heli_fuel_received: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.heli_fuel_received,
            petrol_received: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.petrol_received,
            lo_received: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.lo_received,
            campaign: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.campaign,
            projectLeader: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.projectLeader,
            visitorsOpen: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.visitorsOpen,
            fundsOpen: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.fundsOpen,
            vipsOpen: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.vipsOpen,
            pressOpen: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.pressOpen,
            volsOpen: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.volsOpen,
            officeOpen: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.officeOpen,
            clockChange: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.clockChange,
            operPrepared: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.operPrepared,
            techPrepared: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.techPrepared,
            port_of_call: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.port_of_call|| "No Author Defined",
            time_zone: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.time_zone,
            report_date: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.report_date,
            report_by: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.report_by,
            berth_anchor_hours: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.berth_anchor_hours,
            ship_activity: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.ship_activity,
            uuid: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.uuid,
            is_submit: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.is_submit,
            helicopter_used: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.helicopter_used,
            position_lat: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.position_lat,
            position_lon: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.position_lon,
            me1_distance: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.me1_distance,
            me1_uw_hours: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.me1_uw_hours,
            me2_distance: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.me2_distance,
            me2_uw_hours: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.me2_uw_hours,
            me1_2_distance: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.me1_2_distance,
            me1_2_uw_hours: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.me1_2_uw_hours,
            edrive_distance: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.edrive_distance,
            edrive_uw_hours: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.edrive_uw_hours,
            sail_distance: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.sail_distance,
            sail_uw_hours: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.sail_uw_hours,
            e_motorsail_distance: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.e_motorsail_distance,
            e_motorsail_uw_hours: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.e_motorsail_uw_hours,
            me_motorsail_distance: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.me_motorsail_distance,
            me_motorsail_uw_hours: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.me_motorsail_uw_hours,
            motoring_edrive_distance: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.motoring_edrive_distance,
            motoring_edrive_uw_hours: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.motoring_edrive_uw_hours,
            drifting_hours: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.drifting_hours,
            country: resp.data.noon_report[artno].noon_report.author          
          };
          console.log("ROW TO INSERT " + JSON.stringify(row));
          insertBigQuery(row, table);
        }
        console.log("For Loop end");
        res.status(200).send("OK");
      }
      catch (error) {
        // Handle the error
        console.log(error);
        response.status(500).send(error);
      }
    })
  }
  catch (error) {
      // Handle the error
      console.log(error);
      response.status(500).send(error);
    }

    //This Query inserts data after charges completed
    async function insertBigQuery(row, table){
     return await table.insert(row, function(err, apiResponse) {
        //console.log('Insert', apiResponse);
        if (!err) {
         console.log("[BIGQUERY] - Saved.");
        } else {
        console.error(`error table.insert: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`)
         // To finish http function return value
        }
      });
    }
});
```

`

I have a for loop to unpack the REStFul API data and build a row to insert into BigQuery. I use the Cloud scheduler to trigger this function with the HTTP trigger.

The URL I'm using is for an internal app, so this is not available on the outside. I get the data and I unpack the data, the function finish before the data has been inserted into BigQuery.

I tried to add an await to the line where I call the BigQuery insert function, that did not work.

```
await insertBigQuery(row, table);
```

It did not work, looking for help.

Comment: Adding `await` to `insertBigQuery` is a step in the right direction have you also added `async` to your arrow function `async resp =>` (line 66). If this doesn't help I suggest to add some log print at the important place in the code and share them which can help identify the issue. For best practice, I suggest not to use `var` for row rather use `let` and define the let outside of the `for loop`. I would typically avoid to directly return an await from `insertBigQuery` rather put the result into a let which will make it easier to debugg your code

Answer (score 1):

I think I see a couple of issues.  If we look at the API for BigQuery table objects called `insert`, we see that it returns a Promise.  Great.  We also see that it has an optional callback function.  I'm not certain that you should use both.  You either say the outcome will be known be a promise that will be subsequently resolved or you say that the outcome will be told to you via a callback.  I'm not sure that both will be satisfied.  I'd suggest just using Promises.

However, I think the bigger issue is with this logic:

```
async function insertBigQuery(row, table){
  return await table.insert(row, function(err, apiResponse) {
    //console.log('Insert', apiResponse);
    if (!err) {
      console.log("[BIGQUERY] - Saved.");
     } else {
       console.error(`error table.insert: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`)
       // To finish http function return value
     }
  });
}
```

Netting this down .... you have:

```
async function funcName() {
   return await asyncFuncCall();
}
```

I think this may be your problem.  By prefixing your function (`funcName`) with `async` you are declaring that the function will return a `Promise` and that the caller will NOT block waiting for the return but the caller will itself receive a promise.

Ive got a sneaky suspicion that what you really might want to have is:

```
async function funcName() {
   return asyncFuncCall();
}
```

and then where you are calling funcName() you want either:

```
let finalResult = await funcName();
```

or

```
funcName().then((finalResult) => { ... logic ... });
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try out your suggestion.